# Create an Airflow DAG to write execution date to a sql table in bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm thinking of creating a DAG in airflow to write to the below table. Created a table using below sql statement:
**CREATE TABLE `np.TEMP.DAG_TEST_TABLE`
( generated_date DATE, bq_ts TIMESTAMP)
PARTITION BY generated_date**

I would like to write a query that outputs the logical date of my DAG run and then write to generated_date column in the above sql table.I also want to use {{ ds }} to calculate the logical DAG run date.for ex, if I run the DAG in the past like Aug 20,2023 but its physically running on Sep 26 then generated_date should be written as '2023-08-20' and bq_ts = '2023-09-26'(the day we are running).Can someone help me with syntax to create the above DAG.

EXEC_DATE='{{ ds }}'
TABLE_ID = "DAG_TEST_TABLE${}".format('{{ ds }}')